# How do I fix CATransform3D redefinition error on Xcode with iOSOpenDev?

Tags: ios, xcode, catransform3d

Yesterday, as iOS 6 Jailbreak was released, I decided to learn how to program tweaks. I've been searching some info about it and I've seen that iOSOpenDev is the right tool to create them.

The problem is that I don't know how to start. For example, I create a simple "Hello World" as a Notification Center Widget but an error happens in a Springboard header file:

[image]

I've searched some info about this error but I don't understand how should I fix it. Pages I've found are this pair:

- https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev/issues/29
- https://github.com/kokoabim/iOSOpenDev/issues/23

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:** If something is defined then it cannot be redefined, which is happening with CATransform3D.

**Resolve:** Simply commet-out the definition that is producing the error. Or, wrap it using preprocessor logic to "know" if it has already been defined (which requires its original definition to indicate that it has).

**FYI:** Latest iOSOpenDev installation has this commented-out.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put the "#define CATransform3D 1" above the line above it.